# What is the best way to access data from file in random?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, file-io, fstream

I have been searching for an answer for this question, but I found none. I'm currently using `fstream` to open a file on the hard-disk with flags `std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary` for random access.

The data present in the file are records and each record is of size `16 bytes`. And it took about `0.479604 seconds` to write `336.357 kb` of records to the file in parallel (two threads). I didn't use any specific strategy to perform the read write operation optimally. And without threads, the same operation took `0.352716 seconds` (the time difference is as expected).

These are the methods I used for performing the read write operations:

```
void FileBascIO::createFile(const std::string& fName) {
    std::fstream fcreate(fName.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
}


FileBascIO::returnTypeRead FileBascIO::readFromFile(const std::string& fName, int64_t pos,
                        FileFlagType relativeInitial, char* data, uint64_t size) {

    std::fstream fio (fName.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    fio.seekg(pos, relativeInitial);
    return fio.read(data, size);
}


FileBascIO::returnTypeWrite FileBascIO::writeToFile(const std::string& fName, int64_t pos,
                        FileFlagType relativeInitial, char* data, uint64_t size) {

    std::fstream fio (fName.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);

    if (!fio) {
        fio.close();
        fio.clear();
        createFile (fName);
        fio.open(fName.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
    }
    fio.seekp(pos, relativeInitial);
    return fio.write(data, size);
}
```

The above code is not efficient and I don't know any ways of making it efficient. I did a bit of searching on this and I came to understand that the entire file or a large block of the file should be pre-read and stored in the RAM, before performing the operations. This is because the physical position of the data in the hard-disk matters. And once the fields get updated, the entire file must be written back to the hard-disk in large blocks.

In the example of writing 16 bytes to the file sequentially, won't it be better to first store the data in the RAM memory first and write that to the file in large blocks? If I were to do this manually, what block size should I choose? What is the best alternate way to implement random read/write access more efficiently?

**EDIT**

From the following comments, the best way to solve this problem will be to use a memory-map of the file, and let the operating system take care of all the optimization stuff as @Sami Kuhmonen pointed out. I haven't tried this out yet. Another suggestion was to not close and open the files multiple times as @Jean-Baptiste Yunès pointed it out. After applying that solution, now the code runs in 0.166191 seconds even with the threads.

The updated source:

**In the header**

```
    struct FstreamPtrContainer {
    std::map <std::string, std::fstream*> fileStreamMap;
    ~FstreamPtrContainer();
};

struct FileBascIO{



    static FstreamPtrContainer fileStreamContainer;

    typedef decltype( ((std::fstream*) nullptr)->read((char*) nullptr, uint64_t() ))  returnTypeRead;
    typedef decltype( ((std::fstream*) nullptr)->write((char*) nullptr, uint64_t() )) returnTypeWrite;
    typedef decltype( std::ios_base::beg )                                            FileFlagType;

    static returnTypeRead readFromFile (const std::string& fName, int64_t pos,
                                        FileFlagType relativeInitial, char* data, uint64_t size);

    static returnTypeWrite writeToFile (const std::string& fName, int64_t pos,
                                        FileFlagType relativeInitial, char* data, uint64_t size);

    static void createFile (const std::string& fName);

    static void flushAll();

};
```

**In the cpp file**

```
FstreamPtrContainer::~FstreamPtrContainer() {
    for (auto it : fileStreamMap){
        it.second->close();
        delete it.second;
    }
}



FstreamPtrContainer FileBascIO::fileStreamContainer;

void FileBascIO::createFile(const std::string& fName) {
    std::fstream fcreate(fName.c_str(), std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
}

void FileBascIO::flushAll() {
    for (auto it : fileStreamContainer.fileStreamMap) {
        it.second->flush();
    }
}


FileBascIO::returnTypeRead FileBascIO::readFromFile(const std::string& fName, int64_t pos,
                        FileFlagType relativeInitial, char* data, uint64_t size) {

    auto it = fileStreamContainer.fileStreamMap.find(fName);
    std::fstream* fio;

    if (it == fileStreamContainer.fileStreamMap.end()) {
        fio =  new std::fstream (fName.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        fileStreamContainer.fileStreamMap [fName] = fio;
    }
    else {
        fio = it->second;
        fio->flush();
    }

    fio->seekg(pos, relativeInitial);
    return fio->read(data, size);
}


FileBascIO::returnTypeWrite FileBascIO::writeToFile(const std::string& fName, int64_t pos,
                        FileFlagType relativeInitial, char* data, uint64_t size) {

    auto it = fileStreamContainer.fileStreamMap.find(fName);
    std::fstream* fio;

    if (it == fileStreamContainer.fileStreamMap.end())  {
        fio  = new std::fstream(fName.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);

        if (!(*fio)) {
            fio->close();
            fio->clear();
            createFile (fName);
            fio->open(fName.c_str(), std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
        }

        fileStreamContainer.fileStreamMap [fName] = fio;

    } else{
        fio = it->second;
        fio->flush();
    }

    fio->seekp(pos, relativeInitial);
    return fio->write(data, size);
}
```

Now the execution time has almost halved.

Comment: Memory mapping might be of use and it would handle all the lower level stuff for you.

Comment: Generally writing large blocks is more efficient than writing small blocks. What are you actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: By "small" I meant buffers of size of a few bytes. I'm trying to find an efficient way to perform random read/write access.

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen, "Memory mapping" seems like a method I must try out. Thanks.

Comment: Write code to cache a larger number of 16-byte blocks - or, unless the file is absolutely enormous, load the entire file (or use memory mapping of the file - but that's basically "cache larger number of 16-byte blocks via the OS")

Comment: You may change the buffer behind the scene of your `fstream`, but first don't open and close the file each time you need to read or write, this is absolutely un-necessary and very time-consuming.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès Thanks, now I have `execution time in seconds:0.166191` execution time.

Comment: Is there a limit to how many fstream objects I can have simultaneously opened ?